# I use Firebase for phone authentication it work on mobile debug but error on signed APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Error:**
 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]

Comment: You need to add SHA-1 key for your project inside of your firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

You must re-generate SHA-1 by using your keystore, which is used to sign your APK. Then add generated SHA-1 to your firebase project configure.

For example: your keystore is: `abc.keystore`. Let run below statement to generate SHA-1

`keytool -exportcert -alias <your_keystore_alias> -keystore <path_to_file>/abc.keystore -list -v -storepass android`

Then copy the output SHA-1 in console and add to settings of your Firebase project

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command in command prompt:

`keytool -exportcert -alias <your_keystore_alias> -keystore <path_to_file>/key_name.keystore -list -v -storepass android`

Once `SHA-1` is generated, set it in Firebase console.

Note `JAVA_HOME` has to be set on Path variable in System Settings.